# i can't bring back my sound with pacmd in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

i want to bring back my voice the `pacmd list-cards` command show me this

```
1 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_03.0>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 6
properties:
    alsa.card = "0"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf731c000 irq 53"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:03.0"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "8086"
    device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
    device.product.id = "160c"
    device.product.name = "Broadwell-U Audio Controller"
    device.form_factor = "internal"
    device.string = "0"
    device.description = "Built-in Audio"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 100, available: no)
    off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
sinks:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
sources:
    alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

when i use `pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo`there is no voice

Comment: check `pavucontrol` that sound level is not muted or level set to 0.
check same in `alsamixer`

Comment: no no i check that first look at the part "available: no" i think that is my problem